# how could i use ionicons with tailwind CSS?

Tags: tailwind-css, ionicons

I want to use only ionicons with tailwind CSS not ionic framework.

```
<ion-icon name="add-circle" className="text-2xl"></ion-icon>
```

this code is not work.

```
<ion-icon name="add-circle" class="md hydrated text-2xl"></ion-icon>
```

it works. but i think maybe it is not good way. there are another way?